# no match for 'operator='

Tags: c++, stack, structure

I have built a static stack of structures, and everything works - including creating an array of the structures. However, for some reason I can't set the top of the array to a structure.

In my `.cpp` file, in my `push` function, I keep erroring on the following line:

```
stackArray[top] = newStudent;
```

The error I am receiving is:

> "51: no match for 'operator=' in '*(((studentstack*)this)->studentstack::stackArray + (+(((unsigned int)((studentstack*)this)->studentstack::top) * 24u))) = ((studentstack*)this)->studentstack::newStudent' "

I am including my code below.

Header file:

```
#ifndef studentstack_H
#define studentstack_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class studentstack {
    private:
        int size;         // Stack size
        int top;          // Top of the Stack

        struct student {
            int ID;
            string Name;
            string Address;
            double GPA; 
        };
        student * stackArray;  // Pointer to the stack
        student * newStudent; // Pointer to the new student

    public: //Constructor
        studentstack(int);

        // Copy Constructor
        studentstack(const studentstack &);

        //Destructor
        ~studentstack();

        //Stack Operaations
        void push(string, int, double, string);
        void pop(int &);
        bool isFull() const;
        bool isEmpty() const;
    };

#endif
```

studentstack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "studentstack.h"

using namespace std;

studentstack::studentstack(int SIZE) {
    stackArray = new student[SIZE];
    size = SIZE;
    top = -1;
    int ID = 0;
    double GPA = 0;
}

studentstack::studentstack(const studentstack &obj) {
    if (obj.size > 0)
        stackArray = new student[obj.size];
    else
        stackArray = NULL;

    size = obj.size;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        stackArray[count] = obj.stackArray[count];

    top = obj.top;
}

studentstack::~studentstack() {
    delete [] stackArray;
}

void studentstack::push(string name, int id, double gpa, string address) {
    if (isFull()) {
        cout << "The stack is full.\n";
    } else {
        top++;
        newStudent = new student;
        newStudent-> Name = name;
        newStudent-> ID = id;
        newStudent-> Address = address;
        newStudent-> GPA = gpa;
        stackArray[top] = newStudent;
    }
}   

void studentstack::pop(int &id) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "The stack is empty.\n";
    } else {
        id = stackArray[top].ID;
        top--;
    }
}

bool studentstack::isFull() const {
    bool status;

    if (top == size - 1)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}

bool studentstack::isEmpty() const {
    bool status;

    if (top == -1)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "studentstack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    int id, var;
    string address;
    double gpa;
    studentstack s[20];

    for(int x =0; x<20; x++) {
        cout << "New Student Name: " << endl;
        cin >> name;

        cout << "ID: " << endl;
        cin >> id;

        cout << "GPA: " << endl;
        cin >> gpa;

        cout << "Address: " << endl;
        cin >> address;

        s.push(name, id, gpa, address)
    }

    cout << "Popping: "
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        s.pop(var);
        cout <<var;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign a pointer to a non-pointer.  Try declaring your stackArray as a **, modify your new accordingly and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to cut down the example to a minimal piece of code showing the problem. What it comes down to is that you try to assign a `student*` to a an element in an array of `student` objects. A pointer to an object is different to an object:

```
stackArray[0] = new student(); // does NOT work
stackArray[0] = student();
```

Note, that object are created in C++ by a constructor and not necessarily involving `new`. When you construct and object using `new` you still create an object but you also allocate space for it on the heap. By default, objects are created wherever they are defined. For example, `student()` creates an object on the stack which is then assigned to an object in the memory of `stackArray[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question, but note that your main() cannot work. You declare an array of 20 `studentstack` elements:

```
studentstack s[20];
```

and later on you're doing:

```
s.push(/* ... */);
s.pop(/* ... */);
```

That doesn't make much sense. `s` is not a `studentstack`. It's an *array* of `studentstack`s. Arrays in C++ don't have member functions.